# Is there a service to buy sell and secure crypto currency?

Tags: wallets

Can anyone help ? I have purchased Dentacoin on coinexchange and would like to move them off the exchange into a secure wallet. Im surprised there is not a person or a service being offered to do this!

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Dentacoin is an Ethereum ERC20 token, this is mentioned in their [whitepaper - page 16](https://www.dentacoin.com/white-paper/Whitepaper-en1.pdf) and it can be seen on [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/token/0x08d32b0da63e2C3bcF8019c9c5d849d7a9d791e6), therefore, they can be sent from the exchange to any Ethereum wallet.

Whether it is an account on a local Ethereum node, a multi-sig wallet contract that you have created or a hardware wallet, you should be able to send the Ethereum token Dentacoin to any of these addresses / wallets, that you own, to hold your tokens off of an exchange.